# SQL Join Query taking long to complete

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I am working on a project that require me to join four tables. I have written this code but it's taking forever to finish. Please help. Ohhh I have about 121 000 entries in the Db

```
PortfolioCollectionDataContext context = null;
        context = DataContext;
        var Logins = from bkg in context.EnquiryBookings
                     where bkg.Paid == true
                     from log in context.Logins
                     where log.LoginID == bkg.LoginID
                     from enq in context.Enquiries
                     where enq.EnquiryID == bkg.EnquiryID
                     from estb in context.Establishments
                     where enq.EstablishmentID == estb.EstablishmentID
                     select new
                     {
                         log.LoginID,
                         log.FirstName,
                         log.LastName,
                         log.CountryOfResidence,
                         log.EmailAddress,
                         log.TelephoneNumber,
                         bkg.TotalPrice,
                         estb.CompanyName
                     };

        string str = "";

        foreach (var user in Logins)
        {
            str += ("[Name: " + user.LastName + " " + user.FirstName + " - Country: " + user.CountryOfResidence + " - Phone: " + user.TelephoneNumber + " - Email: " + user.EmailAddress + " - Booked From: " + user.CompanyName + " - Spent: " + user.TotalPrice.ToString() + "]");
        }

        return str;
```

Comment: Why are you using the `from`-`where` syntax for equi-joins? You can use `join` instead. And why not use the association properties instead of writing manual joins? And finally, you might want to have a look at the final query generated, especially it's execution plan. And of course, adding strings together like this is quite inefficient, but you're not saying what timescale is "slow", so it might or might not have a measurable effect.

Comment: I don't know about your db structure but you can remove the ```foreach``` and create ```str``` in ```select new { ... }``` to reducing one more loop.

Comment: I am new to SQL, the process is slow when executing the query, but thanks Luaan I really have a lot to learn

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? That doesn't look like standard SQL at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following query on LINQ

```
PortfolioCollectionDataContext context = null;
        context = DataContext;
        var Logins = from bkg in context.EnquiryBookings
                 join log in context.Logins
                 on log.LoginID equals bkg.LoginID
                 && bkg.Paid == true
                  join enq in context.Enquiries
                     on enq.EnquiryID equals bkg.EnquiryID
                  join estb in context.Establishments
                     on enq.EstablishmentID == estb.EstablishmentID
                  select new
                     {
                   str = "[Name: " + log.LastName + " " + log.FirstName + " - Country: " + log.CountryOfResidence + " - Phone: " 
                       + log.TelephoneNumber + " - Email: " + log.EmailAddress + " - Booked From: " 
                       + estb.CompanyName + " - Spent: " + bkg.TotalPrice.ToString() + "]"
                     };

        string output = string.Join(", ", Logins.ToList());

        return output;
```

Check your query by taking cursor on Logins and paste that query here. Then check an estimated execution plan of your query and paste here.

If using SQL Server, to get execution plan of your query using Sql server management studio, click on an icon highlighted in an image below.

[image]